# Проверка свойства у элемента

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как проверить элемент, есть ли у него свойство value? Если нету то вставить значение через innerHTML.

Comment: У элемента DIV например нету value, а у input есть. Как определить каким способом вставить значение, если мы не знаем какой у нас элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать метод [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if (element.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
    // TODO:
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! 
Думал что hasOwnProperty только свойства объектов проверяет...

Comment: Тоже так думал.